# Apex Class - Else If Statement not firing

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, lightning-experience

New to Salesforce Dev and I know this is probably a very simple fix but I am having an else if statement that is failing to trigger.
In a nutshell when an Opp, Contact or Acc is edited/created and export is performed and an email sent to an external system with all of the field details for that record inside the email.  There are a number of ID fields within that email that the class converts over to User.Alias using IF Statements.  This ensures the system on the other side knows the users name.

// IE: If field = lookup.user then lookup user ID and use Alias as the value in the email.

I am trying to replicate this exact logic for another lookup field on the opportunity.  "Second_Salesperson__c" however when adding in another branch of the if statement this does work as expected UNLESS there is no value in that field.  If the value of that field is NULL the email does not get sent at all.

IF Statement below:

```
Map<String, String> allFields = new Map<String, String>();
        
        for(String fieldTitle : allObjectFields.keySet()) {
            
            Schema.SObjectField field = allObjectFields.get(fieldTitle);
            String fieldName = field.getDescribe().getName();
            String value = '';
            

            if (fieldName == 'OwnerId')     {
                
                String userId   = String.valueOf( obj.get(field) );
                User user       = userMap.get(userId);
                value           = user.Alias;
            }
            else if (fieldName == 'RecordTypeId') {
                
                String rtId     = String.valueOf( obj.get(field) );
                RecordType rt   = recordTypeMap.get(rtId);
                value           = rt.Name;
            }
            else if (fieldName == 'Second_Salesperson__c')     {
                            
                String userId   = String.valueOf( obj.get(field) );
                User user       = userMap.get(userId);
                value           = user.Alias;
            }
            else if (isDeleted && fieldName == 'IsDeleted') {
                value = 'true';
            }
            else {
                value += obj.get(field);
            }
            
            allFields.put(fieldName, value);
        }
        
        return allFields;
    }
```

If there is no value in the Second_Salesperson__c field then it does send fire off the email.  I need to nest a null statement in there which I have not yet figured out.

Greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Grant, welcome to SFSE, would you be able to add a couple of details of what is not working?

Comment: Thanks! 

I have two scnerarios:

1.  A user creates an opportunity and assigns a user to the lookup field (Salesperson__c).

Comment: Thanks! 

I have two scnerarios:
1.  A user creates an opportunity and assigns a user to the lookup field (Second_Salesperson__c).
2. A user creates an opportunity and leaves that (Second_Salesperson__c) field blank.

There is an Apex class "XMLconverter.css" that triggers upon edit an Opportunity and sends an email across to a mailbox which forwards this to an external system in a format dictated by the code.

The XMLConverter worked fine until I added an additional "else if" to the statement to look at the Second_Salesperson__c field.  Since the email doesn't send if no value.

Comment: My ideal scenario is for this email to be sent whether there is a value in the "Second_Salesperson__C" field or not.  If there is a value in that field I need the code to look up the ID of that user and place the Alias in the email - not the ID.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why is you're getting a NullPointerException when there's no value. You need to make sure you're not using null as the value. You can actually rewrite this to be a lot more legible by using a switch statement, and using the `?.` "Safe Navigation Operator" to avoid the NullPointerException. Here's the revised code:

```
Map<String, String> allFields = new Map<String, String>();

for(String fieldTitle : allObjectFields.keySet()) {
    
    Schema.SObjectField field = allObjectFields.get(fieldTitle);
    String fieldName = field.getDescribe().getName();
    String value = String.valueOf(obj.get(field));
    switch on fieldName {
        when 'Second_Salesperson__c', 'OwnerId' {
            value = userMap.get((Id)value)?.Alias;
        }
        when 'RecordTypeId' {
            value = recordTypeMap.get((Id)value)?.Name;
        }
    }            
    allFields.put(fieldName, value);
}
return allFields;
```

Comment: TY greatly, I was halfway down that path so I'm glad you have confirmed it.
Will try this code now and get back to you.

Comment: This didn't work.  I have added in the code and now it doesn't seem to be triggering at all.  Even if I create an Opp with a value in the "Salesperson" field the email is not triggered.  

This wasn't relevant on a field like OwnerId as that always will have a value.

Comment: @Grant The problem must be somewhere else then. You'll need to check your debug logs.